# How to convert HTML to Markdown in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, markdown, html-parsing

I am trying to convert HTML(view) to Markdown. It does work for a simple Tag but not for a view.blade file. Also it doesn't download the file. But my Main problem is that it does not convert a view file to markdown.

I am using Markdownify to convert HTML to Markdown. It does work for a simple HTML Tag but if I use a blade file it does not convert it to Markdown. I seen many Post about how to Convert Markdown to HTML but not so much about the opposite. Also recognized that some asked question is about a simple html string variable and not about a full blade file.

```php
public function export-bladeView-to-markdown()
    {
      $converter = new Markdownify\Converter;
      $converter->parseString(view('exportOfGuideOverview')->render());

      dd($converter);
    }
```

The Output of the is Code is this is not markdown. Its an Object of Converter and the Output is still the same. Its HTML and not Markdown.

```php
public function export-bladeView-to-markdown()
    {
      $converter = new Markdownify\Converter;
      $converter->parseString(<h1> Hello </h1>);

      dd($converter);
    }
```

The above code will save to output # Hello World. This will work

Hopefully you guys can Help me.

Comment: If you pass the contents of `view('exportOfGuideOverview')->render()` to `parseString()` function, it works?

Comment: no it doesn't work. I get HTML instead of Markdown.